# Magento How to show all products of subcatgories by one collection

Tags: php, magento

Hello I am having a Category-Ids of subcategories of particular category so i want to get all the Products of all the sub category of that particular parent category. so how to get that products.

```
Suppose I have parent category 4 and it's having 5,6,7,8,9,10,11 as a child category so i Then I want all the products of 5,6,7,8,9,10,11's category using single query.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load('4')->getChildrenCategories();

foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $collection = $category->getProductCollection();
    foreach ($collection as $product) {
        $result[] = $product;
    }
}
```

This should work even if you don't know id's of the subcategories.

Answer (score 0):

You should join product collection with catalog_category_product_index table. See Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection, method _applyProductLimitations().

The ready solution will be something like this (just an idea, may be some modifications or filters should be needed):

```
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$productCollection
    ->getSelect()->join(
            array('cat_index' => $this->getTable('catalog/category_product_index')),
            'cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id',
            array()
        )
    ->where('cat_index.category_id in (?)', $categoryIds);
```